# После обновления Gradle не поддерживает градиент

Tags: android, xml, gradle, material-design

Обновил `Gradle` с версии 23 до 24. На версии 23 градиент (разметку которого укажу ниже) работал исправно и никаких проблем не создавал.

Сейчас картина следующая:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asgard.power"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.4'
}
```

Так он выглядит на данный момент. Еще пробовал просто на `24.0.0` версиях.

Выдает ошибку:
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>` (почему unknown без понятия, раньше там был класс, при попытке повторно воспроизвести баг, поменял его на это).

Градиент:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#1273A8"
                android:centerColor="#52BAD1"
                android:endColor="#1273A8"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Ругался раньше на этот виджет:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">
```

Стоит убрать бэкграунд - все работает.

UPD полный стектрейс:

> 09-13 14:03:42.841 10057-10057/com.asgard.power E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.asgard.power, PID: 10057
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.asgard.power/com.asgard.power.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
>                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>                                                                         at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                         at com.asgard.power.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>                                                                         at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                         at com.asgard.power.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68) 
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of
>   null array
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onCreateDrawableState(AppBarLayout.java:494)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:16502)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:16737)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:16674)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.(View.java:4203)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:524)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:215)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:211)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:206)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.(AppBarLayout.java:151)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                         at com.asgard.power.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68) 
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

На всякий случай всю разметку перенес:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:clickable="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/framesheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.asgard.power.ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:background="#757575"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Force"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                            android:text="noun"
                            android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                            android:text="One posessing or exercising power or influence or authority"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                            android:text="usage:the misterious presence of evil power; may the force be with you; the forces of evil "
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                            android:text="noun"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_main" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите версию градла

Comment: Это не `версия Gradle`, это версия Android SDK. Покажите полный стактрейс ошибки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с удовольствием бы, но `IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4 and 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4 (moments ago)`

Comment: @Asgard, а вот это уже похоже на конфликт в SDK - попробуйте снести его нафиг и скачать заново.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб смогу последовать совету лишь после возвращения из универа, надеюсь, еще будете здесь.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `gradle 2.14.1` обновился только что, ошибка та же, обновил студию, библиотеку поддержки - все до последнего.

Comment: @metalurgus gotcha

Comment: @Asgard, попробуйте не харкодить цвета в разметке, а вынести из в ресурсы и прописать ссылки на них вместо нынешнего состояния